# Getting Correlation ID: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 in Content Search Webpart

Tags: 2013, content-search-web-part, display-template

I keep on getting:

**Sorry, Something went wrong.**

```
Correlation ID: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

in my Content Search Webpart. The Content Search Webpart is configured to get results limited by a Custom Content Type (Custom Page Contenttype) and a Custom Display Template (does some JavaScript for Image Rendering). Sometimes the CorrelationID 000.. showes up, and sometimes not. When I press `Strg+F5` it works most of the time. I have also seen [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/f7b8a70e-5663-4532-9327-3c15da58cfca/correlation-id-00000000000000000000000000000000-error-in-content-search-sometimes?forum=sharepointadmin) article and tried the following code:

```
$myfarm = Get-SPFarm
$myfarm.XsltTransformTimeOut
$myfarm.XsltTransformTimeOut = 15
$myfarm.Update()
```

Even I tried it with 15 seconds but I haven't seen any effect. 
Does anyone know the reason why this happens or can give me a soloution for this fault?

**EDIT_1**

Here is the report. I couldn't find `state: Degrade` but I did a Index-Reset and a Full Crawl anyway because it is just a developement machine and mabey it helps. And testing it for a while, i came to the decision it could have helped. I didn't recieve the sorry something went wrong dialog in the last hour. If I don't recieve it in the next month again, I'll accepet your answer. Thank you for your response.

Report:

```
> Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication | Get-SPEnter
priseSearchStatus -Text
Name      : IndexComponent1
State     : Active
Primary   : True
Partition : 0
Host      : sepp0019

Name      : Cell:IndexComponent1-SP18556ba382adI.0.0
State     : Active
Primary   : True
Partition : 0

Name  : Partition:0
State : Active

Name  : AdminComponent1
State : Active
Host  : sepp0019

Name  : QueryProcessingComponent1
State : Active
Host  : sepp0019

Name  : ContentProcessingComponent1
State : Active
Host  : sepp0019

Name  : AnalyticsProcessingComponent1
State : Active
Host  : sepp0019

Name  : CrawlComponent0
State : Active
Host  : SEPP0019
```

**EDIT_2**

Today I finished the updates you suggested. I'm not sure if it helped but it seems to work now. I'll let you know when I am sure that the problem doesn't occour again. Thank you very much for the immediate answers.

Comment: Does the CSWP use XSLT to manipulate the results?  I don't think it does.

Comment: No, I don't use XSLT. Just a little bit of JavaScript and CSS to display the results in a way like Bootstraps "Carousel".

Comment: I was pointing out why `XsltTransformTimeOut` didn't work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Make sure that you have installed the current software update for SharePoint.
> 2. Check your current timeout settings, simply use the following PowerShell:

```
 $myfarm = Get-SPFarm> 
 $myfarm.XsltTransformTimeOut
 $myfarm.XsltTransformTimeOut = 5
 $myfarm.Update()
```

> If you’re experiencing the above problem, you probably got a 1 back
>   from the above command indicating that the timeout is currently set to
>   1 second. To set it to a more reasonable value (we choose the original
>   5 seconds) just do this (assuming you set the $myfarm object using the
>   above powershell):

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/f7b8a70e-5663-4532-9327-3c15da58cfca/correlation-id-00000000000000000000000000000000-error-in-content-search-sometimes?forum=sharepointadmin

**EDIT**

goto powershell and do the following:

```
Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication | Get-SPEnterpriseSearchStatus -Text
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219672.aspx

can you post back within your question the result? do you see `state : Degraded` within the report? if so reset the search index:

**To reset the content index**

> 1.Verify that the user account that is performing this procedure is a service application administrator for the Search service application
>   for which you want to reset the content index.
>
> 2.On the SharePoint Central Administration home page, in the Application Management section, click Manage service applications.
>
> 3.On the Manage Search Applications page, click the Search service application for which you want to reset the content index.
>
> 4.On the Search Service Application: Search Administration page, in the Quick Launch, in the Crawling section, click Index Reset.
>
> 5.On the Search Service Application: Index Reset page, verify that the Deactivate search alerts during reset check box is checked, and then
>   click Reset Now.
>
> 6.In the confirmation dialog box that appears, click OK to confirm the content index reset.
>
> The Search Service Application: Search Administration page opens and
>   the System Status is displayed.
>
> 7.Perform a full crawl.

[image]

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff608191(v=office.14).aspx

**EDIT**

I need to know if you have updated sharepoint since you downloaded it? as this sounds like a bug that is fixed with the current updates released:

update your server with the following updates that should resolve this issue as the above method should of worked:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2767999

and then do this:

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;2726992

You must do the first link first before you do the second as the second update is reliant on the first update!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as you can see in my Question i already tried it with 15 seconds. And still get this message.

Comment: just ammended my answer, should hopefully get your search working again!

Comment: Just edited my Question, the dialog didn't show up in the last hour, since i made a index reset and a full crawl. Mabey this realy helped. But I once tried this, but the message came again. If it doesn't show up the next month, I'll mark your answer as accepted. Thank you verry much!

Comment: no probs! sounds like it didnt index in the first place but lets hope that it sticks this time ;) the state is active now what is a good sign! next time you get into the same error just print out the text report to check!

Comment: Happend again.. Report showes everything is still active:

Comment: Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication | Get-SPEnter
priseSearchStatus -Text
Name      : IndexComponent1
State     : Active
Primary   : True
Partition : 0
Host      : sepp0019

Name      : Cell:IndexComponent1-SP18556ba382adI.0.0
State     : Active
Primary   : True
Partition : 0

Name  : Partition:0
State : Active

Name  : AdminComponent1
State : Active
Host  : sepp0019

Name  : QueryProcessingComponent1
State : Active
Host  : sepp0019

Name  : ContentProcessingComponent1
State : Active

Name  : AnalyticsProcessingComponent1
State : Active
Name  : CrawlComponent0
State : Active

Comment: just ammended my answer!

Comment: Today I finished the updates you suggested. I'm not sure if it helped but it seems to work now. I'll let you know when I am sure that the problem doesn't occour again. Thank you very much for the immediate answers.

Comment: no probs! that update should fix most issues!!